# Need some tips which localization method to use for my NAO robot (robotic)

Tags: localization, orientation, project-management, robotics, nao-robot

for university I'm working on a project in which I have to teach a robot(Nao-robot) play nine men's morris. Unfortunately I'm fairly new to the area of robotics and I need some tips how to solve some problems. Currently I'm working on the localization/orientation of the robot and I'm wondering which approach of localization would fit best in my project.

**A short explanation of the project:**
The robot has a fixed starting position and has to walk around on a boardwhich has a size of about 3x3 meter ( I will post a picture of the board when i reach 10 reputation). There are no obstacles on the field except the game tokens and the game lines are marked yellow on the board. For orientation I use the two camera devices the robot has.

I found some approaches like

**Monte Carlo Localization**

**SLAM** (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping)

but these approaches seem to be quite complex for a beginner like me and I would really appreciate if some has some good ideas what would be a simpler way to solve this problem. Functionality has for me a far higher priority than performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have vague knowledge about the nine men's morris game as such, but I will try to give you my simpler idea.

First thing first, you need to have a map of your board. This should be easy in your case, cause your environment is static. There are few [technique](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/introduction-129/an-introduction-to-mapping-and-localization-3274/) to do this mapping from your board. For your case I would suggest to have a metric map, which is an occupancy grid. Assign coordinates to each cell in the grid. This will be helpful in robot navigation.

As you have mentioned, your robot starts from a fixed position. On start up, initialize your robot with this reference location and orientation (with respect to X-Y axes of the grid, may be you don't need the cameras, I am not sure!!). By initialization I mean, mark your position on the grid.

Use [Dead Reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) for localization and keep updating position and orientation of your robot as it move through the board. I would hope that your robot get some feedback from the servos, like number of rotations and so forth. Do that math and update the position coordinates of your robot as it move into different cell in the grid.

You can use [A-Star](http://wiki.gamegardens.com/Path_Finding_Tutorial) algorithm to find a path for your robot. You need to do the path planning before you want to navigate. You also have to mark those game tokens on the grid, to avoid collisions in planning the path.